# file.getOwner() returns 'DriveUser' value instead of actual owner of the file in google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to display each file details from this folder in google drive, but the .getOwner() method return 'DriveUser'. The files was uploaded by someone and me. So if you check manually in the drive you can see the name of the uploader/owner of each file.

```
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('18MW-6bpYyqQUx9floFgdmKnKIBcd2NZhvTK');
    var files = folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()){
        file = files.next();

        Logger.log(file.getName());
        Logger.log(file.getSize());
        Logger.log(file.getOwner());
        Logger.log(file.getDateCreated());

    }
```

The other file methods return correct value except to getOwner() method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this modification? `getOwner()` returns an object of `user`. So in order to retrieve the name, please use the method of `getName()`.

#### Modified script

From:

```
Logger.log(file.getOwner());
```

To:

```
Logger.log(file.getOwner().getName());
```

#### References:

- [getOwner()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file.html#getOwner())
- [Class User](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/user.html)

Comment: @noyruto88 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.